# Better way of doing giant formatted data objects in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm converting my existing blog, [Code Insider](http://codeinsider.us), to Jekyll. Currently it's a simple static site backed by flask + frozenflask with some custom functions, and Jekyll seems to have a good community around it, so I figured I may as well start using it instead of my existing semi-janky custom setup.

What makes this interesting is that the blog content is nontrivial, and highly structured. There are three "conversations in every post ( codeinsider.us/i/5.html ) and they have a name, description, img headshot, and set of QAs attached. THere's also metadata bout the issue itself (name, introduction, timestamp, etc)

Basically what I'm doing now is assigning each question-answer pair of strings to a tuple, shoving that into a list, assigning the list to a a Conversation dict, shoving each Conversation into a list. The list of Conversations, plus metadata, is the entirety of my blog's content.

Converting this to Jekyll has been a bit interesting. Jekyll doesn't do dynamism well in its front matter or the page content object.

I've basically settled on a "hack" that exploits Jekyll's front matter - in each Jekyll Post that corresponds to a conversation, I'm creating a list-of-dicts

```
name: "Interview with Vincent"
intro: "Hello this is the intro"
title: "CoderPad interview"
conversations:
    -name: "Vincent"
    qas: 
        -question: "First question"
         answer: "First answer"
    -name: "John"
    qas: 
        -question: "Second question"
         answer: "Second answer"
        -question: "Third question"
         answer: "Third answer"
```

etc. Is there a better way of doing this in Jekyll? Keep in mind that these question/answers can be *very* long.

Here's the core loop in the parent template that I'm trying to implement, and have data passed to. That `conversations` object is currently what's in the big YAML blob.

```
{% for conversation in conversations %}
    <img src="{{ conversation.headshot_img }}"/>
    {% for qas in conversation.qas %}
        {{ qas.question }}
        {{ qas.answer }}
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The last time I was doing a similar (insane?) thing (https://github.com/D-side/geekparty4) I found a bug in GitHub's YAML visualizer and they've fixed it. I suppose this is just not the purpose of Jekyll, it aims for simplicity. They've added `_data` files with JSON support recently (with Jekyll 2), that might help a little.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a good way to optimize writing of your posts.

```
---
interview metadatas ...
---
{% include interview.html %}
```

_includes/interview.html

```
---
metadatas ...
---
<h2>{{ page.name }}</h2>
....
{% for conversation in page.conversations %}
{{ conversation.name }}
    {% for qas in conversation.qas %}
        {{ qas.question }}
        {{ qas.answer }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to use markdown in your interview metadatas, you can output it with :

`{{ page.introduction | markdownify }}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer David. I feel that it does't help the core repetition unfortunately, because I need a way to implement  this core loop (see Update)